# Non-Custom uitableviewcell Style is ignored

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm not doing anything tricky. Using the standard TableView Controller from the default template provided by Apple, I just changed the Style to "Subtitle". The change is reflected in the storyboard however it remains basic in the simulator.

The only modifications to the project are:
- I imbedded the navigation controller in a tab controller
- I inserted a search bar and search display controller in the tableview
- I added an object to import XML data from a web site

This project is a bare bones (stripped down) version of a different project that is active in production now but uses only NSDictionary instead of core data. This new project is my attempt to learn care data however I can't get past this pesky problem.

I changed my cell identifier from "Cell" to "aeJobCell" without updating the code and the app ran successfully anyway. It didn't complain that there was no cell identifier of "Cell". Then I put a test in my code to make sure it was using the correct identifier and it was. The labels are getting set properly. The data shows up in the cell however I don't get the subtitle.

I do not have enough reputation to post images, sorry. I'll paste code and describe what I have as best as I can.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    ImportedAEJob *aeJob = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"aeJobCell"];
        aeJob = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"aeJobCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        aeJob = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"aeJobCell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }
    //[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell forAEJob:aeJob];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //    NSString *aJobNo = [[object valueForKey:@"aeJobNo"] description];
    //    NSString *aDeliverTo = [[object valueForKey:@"aeDeliverTo"] description];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"aeJobNo"] description];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"aeDeliverTo"] description];
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forAEJob:(ImportedAEJob *)aeJob
{
//    NSString *aJobNo = aeJob.aeJobNo;
//    NSString *aDeliverTo = aeJob.aeDeliverTo;
    cell.textLabel.text = aeJob.aeJobNo;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aeJob.aeDeliverTo;
}
```

I've reset content and settings, deleted the derived data, restarted my computer, tapped my belly and rubbed my head (and visa versa). I've read more than a dozen posts on this forum but not one of them discusses this specific problem. Most posts regarding cells not displaying properly involve a custom cell, but I am not using a custom cell. I don't even know how to actually.

I've reached the limits of my capacity on this problem. Please help.

```
<----- EDIT ------->
```

Heres the changes I made the the app delegate, in case this helps:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

        UINavigationController *masterNavigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
        rushMasterViewController *controller = (rushMasterViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    } else {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 0];

        //UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        rushMasterViewController *controller = (rushMasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Did you change the cell type to "subtitle" in IB? If not, that's your problem, because if you made the cell in the storyboard, the cell will never be nil, so the if(Cell == nil) clause won't be executed.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not sure I follow. I thought the storyboard is IB. I just changed the style of the cell that was there already. I did not make it. The template give a basic style cell for free and I changed the style to Subtitle. I am not aware of any other steps required. I'm afraid that might be my problem but I have not found sufficient guidance on the subject anywhere.

Comment: Yes the storyboard is IB (along with xibs), and no, changing the cell type to subtitle there shouldn't be a problem. The fact that you could change the cell identifier to "Cell", and the compiler didn't give you an error is strange. It makes me think you are actually seeing a different table view on screen than the one you set up in IB. I can't say how that would be possible without seeing your project.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it seams to be however I only have one tableview in my project and it's a really basic/simple project. I'll post pictures as soon as I can scrape together a few reputations points.

Comment: If you can post your project somewhere or email it to me, I'd be happy to take a look at it, and see what I can figure out.

Comment: That would be amazing. Hmmm.... Any suggestions how I can do this privately? Can I send a private email through this forum? If I make it public I would have to redact it which would break the project.

Comment: You can send it to me directly at rdelmar@comcast.net

Comment: Wow, thank you @rdelmar. I can't believe I wasted so much time on this problem and never thought to do that. I removed that one line and it works now.

Comment: I'll post that as an answer so we can close out this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the subtitle didn't show up is because you registered the class with this line:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"aeJobCell"];
```

When you use a cell that comes from the storyboard, whether a UITableViewCell or your own custom class, you shouldn't register anything. If the cell is defined only in code, then you register the class, and if it's made in a xib file, then you register the nib.

Comment: I added that line of code at one point because I saw it was advised in other posts relating to a similar problem with custom cells and I completely forgot about it. I never even thought to look at that part of my code. Thank you so much @rdelmar.